# is "traveling through highway" correct or traveling by highway correct

Tags: grammar

which sentence is correct? Traveling "through highway" or "by highway"

Comment: By highway.  But you could travel through a tunnel when travelling  by highway.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule of thumb, when you wish to choose between **through** and **by** in a phrase describing a *means*, that is, how something was accomplished or a goal or destination was reached, use "through" only when the means is abstract:

> We've gotten to where we are through sheer *determination*.

You can use "by" both when the means is concrete, like a vehicle or road, and when it is abstract:

> We reached our final destination by *helicopter*.
>
> The company became the dominant force in the industry by *abuse* of monopoly power.

The absence of a determiner (the so-called "zero" article) indicates that the reference is to a means or mode.

**... by train, by car, by rail, by plane, by boat**

and so the following is *not* a reference to a means or mode but simply to a physical passage:

> The drug lord escaped from prison *through **a** tunnel*.